# Get highest value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, max, array-algorithms

Here is my multidimensional array:

```
$arrOrg = [2, 3, [5, 7, 1], 100, [6, 9, [14, 95]], 78];
```

I want to get the highest value from this array.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$highest = 0;
function getHighest($arr) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if (is_array($arr[$i])) {
            getHighest($arr[$i]);
        } else {
            if ($arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]) {
                $highest = $arr[$i];
            } else {
                $highest = $arr[$i + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return $highest;
}
echo getHighest($arrOrg);
```

But it is giving an incorrect result: `78`

Can you help me out?

Comment: what is current output?

Comment: I am getting 78. Last one is getting outputted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$arrOrg = [2, 3, [5, 7, 1], 100, [6, 9, [14, 95]], 78];
$json   = json_encode($arrOrg);
$json   = str_replace(array('[', ']'), "", $json);
$arr    = explode(",", $json);

echo $maximum = max($arr);
```

EDIT after Vahe Galstyan comment

```
$arrOrg = array(
    2, 
    3,
    array(5, 7, 1), 
    100,
    array(
        6, 
        9, 
        array(14, 95)
    ), 
    78
);

$json = json_encode($arrOrg);
$json = str_replace(array('[', ']'), "", $json);
$arr  = explode(",", $json);

echo $maximum = max($arr);
```

Comment: what if array be something like this? $arrOrg = [2, 3, array(5, 7, 1
), 100, [6, 9, [14, 95]], 78];

Comment: oh, ok )) I misunderstood something)

Comment: No worries mate

Comment: pretty solution!

Comment: @VaheGalstyan : PHP is really funny  language due to these stuffs

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function for that.

```
  function getHighest($array) {
       foreach($array as $key => $value) {
           if (is_array($value)) {
               $array[$key] = getHighest($value);
           }
       }

       sort($array);

       return array_pop($array);
    }

    echo getHighest($arrOrg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without globals, modifying the array or doing extra conversions:

```
funcion getMax ($arr) {
    $max = null;
    foreach ($arr as $act) {
        if (is_array ($act)) {
            $act = getMax ($act);
        }
        if ($max == null || act > $max) {
            $max = $act;
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that convert an array to a json, ... remove "[" and "]", then re-transform a string to an array is not an algorithm to find the max. Anyway, ... in php it works. With few lines. I think is a very pretty solution ^_^.

But I want to give also my two cents to this question with this code.

```
$highest = null;

array_walk_recursive($arrOrg, function($item, $key) use (&$highest) {
    if (!isset($highest) || $highest < $item) {
        $highest = $item;
    }
});

echo $highest;
```

Comment: nitpicking a bit but what if it is an array of all negative numbers?

Comment: Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can also achieve it by array_walk_recursive() and max() like below check the output here https://eval.in/809971

```
<?php
   $arrOrg = [2, 3, [5, 7, 1], 100, [6, 9, [14, 95]], 78];
   $oneD = array();
   array_walk_recursive($arrOrg,function ($a) use (&$oneD){
        $oneD[] = $a;

   });
   echo "Maximum value = ".max($oneD);
```

Comment: @BikashP The currently accepted answer from Sumit is a hacky workaround and _can_ fail if there is a key value that is higher than all other values in the array.  For this reason, this answer is the most concise, clever, robust solution with just two functions and no conditionals. (+1)  Watch it not break where Sumit's will: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/663050c168bce42f5133e223011e5f2f3bc3ff7f

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this method.

```
<?php

$array = [2, 3, [5, 7, 1], 100, [6, 9, [14, 95]], 78];
$highest_value=0;
get_highest_value($array);
function get_highest_value($array){
    foreach($array as $val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            get_highest_value($val);
        }else{
            if($GLOBALS['highest_value'] < $val){
                $GLOBALS['highest_value'] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $highest_value; // output 100
```